# writing a DSL for the .Net platform

Tags: c#, .net

I am thinking of writing a [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) to be run in the .Net environment. I am most likely to implement this in C#, though I am flexible on this.

Is there a recommended online resources that show the main steps involved in writing a DSL for the .Net platform?

Ideally, I would like a resource that would provide at least an overview on the following:

- 'Spec'ing a DSL
- How to map the specs to the .Net framework
- Preferably a helloworld example of a trivial DSL implemented in a .Net language

**[Edit]**

Actually, I have just seen [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/YourFirstDSL.aspx) - but it is slightly dated. Does anyone have a view on whether the article is a good starting point or not (the .Net framework and C# seem to evolve at a very rapid pace)

Comment: You can look at ANTLR (http://www.antlr.org/). I am not certain what you mean when you says map the specs to .NET Fx. Are you looking to build a language and compiler that generates IL code and can use types from FCL easily? If yes then this may not work. I had used ANTLR to parse a formula expression (that used to refer business entities and custom functions) but the parsed tree was then interpreted by my program.

Comment: I want to avoid "low level" parser generators/compiler compilers like lexx/yacc/antlr etc. Basically, I am looking to create a 'toy' .Net language (as a starting template). To be more specific, this 'toy' language will generate CIL code and can use the CLR.

Comment: Given the "D" in "DSL", the first question I'd ask is, "what's the  domain?"
A DSL isn't synonymous with "toy language". It sounds like you're aiming for a small/simple general purpose language, not exactly domain specific.

Comment: Take a look at this article(http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077865/core-java/core-java-creating-dsls-in-java-part-1-what-is-a-domain-specific-language.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are willing to buy a book on the topic, I highly recommend ["DSLs in Boo: Domain Specific Languages in .NET"](http://www.manning.com/rahien/) by Ayende Rahien. Very informative and gently takes you through the process of writing a DSL. The author uses a lightweight .NET language called Boo to serve as basis for the DSL's syntax.

Also you can look into VS2012 corner:

- [Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Visualization & Modeling SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30680)
- [Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Visualization & Modeling SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23025)

Comment: This is the route I chose in the end. I already know Python, so Boo represents the shallowest learning curve for me. BTW, I have since ordered the Book from Amazon (this was even before your post - as I did a little further research myself, shortly after posting the question)

Comment: Microsoft links are dead

Answer (score 6):

There's a bunch of different solutions you could use, including the article you linked, but some other examples from MS...

- FsLex/FsYacc - Ports of the popular Lex and Yacc lexer/parsers for F#, but don't be turned off right away. If you've not used it before, F# has a feature called "pattern matching", which allows you to match very complex constructs (such as walking a tree), without an extensive amount of if/else/or blocks all over. This is perfectly suited to language compiling - because almost all DSL solutions you will find will work by parsing the language into an AST (Abstract syntax tree). In this F# solution, you get a strongly typed tree to work with. You can grab the [F# Parsed Language Started](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jomo_fisher/archive/2010/06/15/use-fslex-and-fsyacc-to-make-a-parser-in-f.aspx) to get you going. (There's plenty of existing grammars for Lex/Yacc that can help you out too).
- [SQL Server Modeling Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=29e4ead0-fd81-42ba-862b-f3589378466a&displaylang=en) (formerly "Oslo") - Contains a language called **M**, formerly broken into several parts, one being MGrammar. It's quite an advanced parser and can save you plenty of time over other grammars - code patterns (or generic grammar rules) and precedence are built in and easy to use. I would perhaps recommend this if you're starting out with parsing, because it comes with a visual tool - Intellipad, which has a 3-panel DSL mode, where you type in your language and some example code - and it'll show you the output AST as you type - it's quite productive to use. The generated AST is a valid M language constructor (MGraph), which can be used with services like SQL and XML. A downside to MGrammar IMO, is that walking the AST from C# or elsewhere is a tiresome process. There's nothing strongly typed, and you're working with objects and searching with strings - awkward and easy to make mistakes. There's some samples on msdn, and some vids on channel9 which can help you get started like this [lengthy overview](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL31/)
- The [Visualization and Modeling SDK](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vsvmsdk) - An entire solution built into VS, which focuses largely on building your with Visual Studio's design tools over code. It comes with a minimum language starter template to help you. Haven't any experience with this to recommend it.

There's plenty of other non-MS solutions, like the one you've mentioned, C# targets for ANTLR etc. These are particularly useful if you're re-using existing grammars - because there's dozens already out there.

Answer (score 2):

You could try JetBrains' [MPS](http://www.jetbrains.com/mps/). It is a very rich and robust ecosystem for generating DSLs. I've never used it myself, so caveat emptor, but it's free so I guess it can't hurt (much) to give it a go.

Comment: Does this generate code for the .Net platform ? I searched the forums + site itself and the answer appears to be no - am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm. I thought it did, but it seems there is only some very preliminary effort in that direction: http://mps-csharp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/.

Answer (score 1):

Check out my open source project [meta#](http://metasharp.codeplex.com). It sounds like what you are looking for.